# How to "make" c++ code into a library for xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

To clarify the clarification:
I know how to create libraries in Xcode using either obj-c or swift. I know how to use these in projects. I know how to compile these projects so everything works. What I do not know is how to take open source C source code (hehe) and build/make/compile it into a library.

---

Just to clarify everything below:
I am looking for a way to use c libraries in a Swift application, this means using Xcode. The c libraries do no have to be build with/in Xcode, I am fine with using other tools.

---

I normally write all the code I use myself and unfortunately I only write Swift in Xcode. So I am a little behind on using frameworks/libraries.
Now I really want to explore Tesseract OCR and I am having trouble building the libraries needed. To me it is better to really understand how this works and be able to do this myself and not just look on Github and find pre-compiled sources.

The projects below both handle this differently. The iOS version uses precompiled Libraries. (.a file) The OSX version uses projects that contain the library files (not yet compiled).

[An iOS compiled version](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS)

[An OSX compiled version](https://github.com/AngusHardie/TesseractOCR-For-Mac)

[libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net) example of a library that can't be just dragged and dropped.

Using brew will only install it as a command line tool, not generate a lib.

[install Tesseract with homebrew](http://blog.matt-swain.com/post/26419042500/installing-tesseract-ocr-on-mac-os-x-lion)

The problem I have is that I know too little about these c libraries, and how to build them to even google this effectively.

My question:

- How do you compile/build the c code into an .a file?
- How do you create an xcode project that builds a framework based on
  the c code? (optional)
- What is the right vocabulary for all this?

I am not looking for a Tesseract specific answer. I want to learn how to do this myself.

[about static libraries](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/)

This article doesn't mention how to actually add the c program and let xcode make it. The part about workspaces is interesting though.

[Article on building c project in Xcode](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/05/xcode-and-the-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/)

This one is actually really relevant. However I can't find the executable in Tesseract for example. All options are greyed out when doing step 5.

This looks pretty : [simple c++ procect](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/)
Why can't tesseract look like that? :)

Comment: Right terminology is "statically linked library". Do a websearch for "xcode build statically linked library"  and you should find a decent tutorial. Probably on SO.

Comment: I tried that before. All articles are about building an xcode project as a library/framework. Not on how to build a c "project" like the linked libjpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **build** Tesseract, follow the instructions for a UNIX system:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

You don't have to, in fact you shouldn't use xcode (which is simply a GUI/frontend) but stick with what each library tells you to use. In some cases it might be possible to build with xcode.
Projects that intend you to use xcode for their building, tend to include a xcode project file.

Apple's compiler is llvm/clang, so it may have some slight differences from Linux's GNU gcc/g++.

**EDIT**

You need to first install leptonica and automake:

```
brew install automake
brew install leptonica
```

Then run the building instructions.
As you will notice during *make install* the library is in

```
/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a
```

And the headers are in:

```
/usr/local/include/tesseract
```

From there on, its a matter of using it in your project.
I tested this on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 with brew and command line tools.

Comment: sorry missed the update. Testing now! -> Worked so fast I can still edit the comment. That is how simple this answer was. Thx! Correct me if I'm wrong, but other libs build like this will also generate a .a file and headers in the locations found above right?

Comment: Most Unix/Linux libraries tend to use those locations (or /usr/lib and /usr/include) but OSX tends to be slightly different quite often.

Answer (score 2):

This is a big question. For the part, I had a recent encounter with Xcode.

> - How do you compile/build the c code into an .a file?

1. Click on Xcode project name `Yourproj` (the root node of the tree on the LHS)
2. Choose the target `Yourtarget` on the TARGETS section
3. Click Build Phases on the upper bar
4. scroll down to Linking section
5. change `Mach-O Type` to `Static Library

As per 'C' language requirement, AFAIK this can be changed on the fly:

1. From the last point above, scroll down to Apple LLVM - Language section
2. change `C Language Dialect` to your choice, say `GNU99`
3. If necessary choose `Compile Sources As`: 'C'
4. Scroll up to `Packaging` and edit `Product Name` to `Yourtarget`
5. Edit `Executable Prefix` to `lib`
6. Edit `Executable Extension` to `.a`

Now the output should become a file like `libYourtarget.a`

> - How do you create an xcode project that builds a framework based on the c code?

YMMV, based on what language you choose. I have not used Swift yet. Just add the `libYourtarget.a` as an Other framework of `Yournewproj`. The proper way of doing this is

1. Click on Xcode project name `Yourproj` (the root node of the tree on the LHS)
2. Click on `Build Phases` on the upper bar
3. Make sure a target is selected on the left
4. Now expand `Link Binary with Libraries` and click on the plus sign and then `Add Other` button
5. Browse to your `libYourtarget.a` file and click open.

This should work. If not, try to get rid of compiling errors as it is YMMV as already mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for using Xcode in your answer. Don't have the time now to test it. Will test this with a random open source lib tonight!

Comment: @RMenke Great! Should you need any help let me know.

Comment: Actually I do. Really retarded at all this. Do I just drag and drop the Tesseract source files into an empty Xcode project and then set it up like in your answer? Don't I also need to set the headers to public? Just using Tesseract as an example. The least specific answer will help me the most.

Comment: @RMenke For static libraries, you should "Copy Files" to include directory within "Product Directory" of instead of other means of publishing headers.

Comment: By the way, the library was interesting and I've spent some time on it. you can find a dirty hack here: [Leptonica](https://github.com/mcku/leptonica-osx) and [Tesseract](https://github.com/mcku/tesseract-osx). Hope this is what you are looking for. What are you going to use them for @RMenke?

Comment: I coupled it with CIDetector and NSDataDetector to read all the things