# Setting up TesseractOCRiOS Correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, tesseract

I'm trying to add the Tesseract OCR to my project, this is the Tesseract iOS project on Github - https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

I've followed the instructions in the wiki page and added a bridging header:

> import <>TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h>

This is what my project looks like - http://postimg.org/image/8hhoq62bf/

And when I try to access the Tesseract library it doesn't show.

How can I install the library correctly?

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812509/how-to-make-c-code-into-a-library-for-xcode)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work